# Outbound Email module buttons stay disabled

Tags: outbound-email

I have installed Outbound Email module, all the 4 services(Queue, Tracking, Bounce and mailer) are running, DBs are all installed and have provided Rights and permissions for Mailing Management. Have tested the same some time back. But now, the whole module is coming as disabled. I am trying to figure out the cause for the same. Can somebody help me on this?
[image: Email buttons are disabled]

Comment: Could you clarify what the issue is? "Coming as disabled" doesn't mean anything to me. What exactly are you seeing and where? Any error messages?

Comment: Peter -- I am not able to see Outbound email folder in any of the publication which means I am not able to add any Mailings/DLs and also the Email Management module in the Top menu is coming as disabled. Let me put an image to clarify the same.

Comment: Consider Peter's answer and please learn to give back to the community as well. So many questions you have asked but lots of them are still marked as unanswered. Would you mind sharing what happened to those scenario - got resolved, still unresolved, none of the answer provided resolved it and you have follow some other path to get it resolved.Please note this is a Give & Take community and not an official SDL Support. Everyone in the community will appreciate your give back to the community

Answer (score 4):

If all of this used to work for you and now it does not, the most likely scenario is that your Outbound E-mail license has expired (or Audience Manager, which it depends upon). The logs will tell you as much, so check the Event Viewer as well as the OE log files on disk.

Answer (score 0):

It was a browser issue. Though there was one error but after fixing that too, it was not working on GC. It is working fine on IE and FF.